# Usage: RealmBase -a <algorithm> [-e <encoding>] <credentials>

Tags: java

I just want to know that why I am not getting output as desired instead of this line as output: **Usage: RealmBase -a  [-e ]**

Here is my **Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="beanScopeDemo" class="com.student.spring.impl.BeanScopeDemo">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here is my **RunClassDemo.java**

```
package com.student.spring.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.student.spring.impl.BeanScopeDemo;

public class RunClassDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String [] {"beans.xml"});
        BeanScopeDemo beanScopeDemo = (BeanScopeDemo) applicationContext.getBean("beanScopeDemo");

        beanScopeDemo.setMessage("Message by Customer A");
        System.out.println("Message : " + beanScopeDemo.getMessage());

        beanScopeDemo.setMessage("Message by Customer B");
        System.out.println("Message : " + beanScopeDemo.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is my **BeanScopeDemo.java**

```
package com.student.spring.impl;

public class BeanScopeDemo {
     String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was not getting the desired output of "Message by Customer A" in class RunClassDemo.java, instead i am getting this line : Usage: RealmBase -a <algorithm> [-e <encoding>] <credentials>

Comment: ok I edit the question.... as u said @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: I followed the example of mkyong's site : here is the link (http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/)

Comment: Ok,I think I understand your problem now. Are you sure that's the class you're running? Because the output doesn't make any sense with the current code in your `main` method.

Comment: ya I am sure i am running RunClassDemo.java which contains main method....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, the desired output but i don't know how it happens.
May be earlier i was running RunClassDemo.java from the **"Run"** button in **toolbar** below the **File menu** in **eclipse kepler**. But now I tried to execute this RunClassDemo.java class from **PackageExplorer** using shortcut key **SHIFT + ALT + X J** and i got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this error is to open the command prompt and go to the location of the file and Type `mvn spring-boot:run` and press **"Enter"**

The reason we have to do this is because sometimes we have to provide initial credential's, so to bypass that we will have to go this way.